# Poor browser performance unhiding a large (>1000 rows, 20 columns) table

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I have a page that uses [jQuery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to tabify a set of HTML tables. We have noticed that the performance switching between tabs can be poor when the tables have large numbers (>1000) of rows.

Following some analysis it turns out that the poor performance is isolated to the `$show.removeClass( "ui-tabs-hide" );` line in the tabs' `showTab` function.

This was proven with a simple webpage containing a table of 20 columns and 1000 rows in a containing div element.

Suspicious of jQuery, we removed all jQuery from the page and ended up with the following pure JavaScript approach:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.tableContainer
    {
        height: 500px;
        width: 800px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    div.hidden
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTable() {
        var x = document.getElementById("theTable");
        x.className = "tableContainer";
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:showTable()">Show</a>
<div id="theTable" class="hidden tableContainer">
<table>
    <!-- 1000 table rows, with 20 cells each -->
</table>
</div>
```

The performance is still poor, taking around one second to show the table both in Firefox 5 and IE8.

Can anyone recommend a more performant approach? (other than paging of the table contents, something we might have to resort to but which will require a reworking of a lot of our code)

Comment: Why would a user want to see 20,000 cells at the same time?

Comment: I know you are looking for something other than `paging of the table contents` but do you really think 1000 rows is usable?  I'd say that once you get around 100 rows the data kind of becomes a blur to end users...

Comment: Agree with the above. Paging / filtering is the answer long-term, but there are a couple of short-term workarounds listed below to see you through...

Comment: +1 for paging. That delay is the browser's rendering, and the only way you can remedy it is by rendering less. The offscreen trick will make switching faster, at the expense of a longer page load time, since that render still has to happen. This is exactly what paging is for.

Comment: What about a JS function with setTimeout that display a couple of rows at time? Much like when AJAXing it's better not to fetch the whole data at the same time in case of huge amount of data, the same is for displaying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the table more than anything. 1000 TRs * however many TDs is a *lot* of DOM elements for the browser to re-render.

The only think I can think of to try is instead of swapping the display css property, try positioning the table off-screen instead to 'hide' it.

Or, alternatively, don't hide it at all. Leave it on the page and 'cover' it with a DIV when you want to 'hide' it.

All that said, this is a gigantic table, so the real solution may be to redesign the page itself. Maybe don't use tabs on the page, and have users launch each page in it's own browser tab or something.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a hidden class (which I suppose has `display: none;`) try hiding the table by using

```
position: relative;
left: -9999999px;
```

I know it's a hack but might work ;-)

Comment: Not a bad idea. You still have to take the hit with the browser figuring out the dimensions of the cells, but you're going to have to take that hit at some point and putting it off the page but not hiding it *should* mean you won't take the hit *again* when re-showing it. (You need units on your `left`, btw.) @Richard will have to muck about with things to get this to play nice with the tabs (since the table will need not to be in the tab being hidden, or you won't get the benefit), but it should be possible...

Comment: ya beat me by a minute. Yes, jquery toggles the display css with tabs. I actually dislike this for a lot of reasons and often roll my own using the off-screen positioning.

Comment: @Richard: Did you make sure the table was no longer in the tab being hidden? Remember you have to take the hit at some point, table rendering is expensive. @Jakub's approach is about not taking that hit *every time* you hide and show the table.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

Comment: I thought it may be related to the browser calculating the width/height of the whole block, and since from what I know visibility:hidden mantains the size of the block (unlike display:none), I thought it could help.

Comment: With `visibility:hidden` the table would still take up space on the page, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

1000 rows won't fit on the users screen (I think :) ).

So why not load rows that fit on the screen (perhaps some more) and when the user scrolls down to the end of the table add some more rows.

Like for example Twitter does.

Answer (score 0):

The fix we decided upon in the end was to implement pagination.